# Java EditText Validation Not Working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to validate user input from a form before submit but it is allowing all empty fields to go through... any ideas? I tried "" instead of null as well...

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
               EditText agencyname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agencyname);
               String agency = agencyname.getText().toString();
                EditText firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
                String first = firstname.getText().toString();
                EditText lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
                String last = lastname.getText().toString();
                EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
                String agencyphone = phone.getText().toString();
                EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                String agencyemail = email.getText().toString();
                if(agency != null || first != null || last != null || agencyphone != null || agencyemail != null){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("android.com.smartchoice", "android.com.smartchoice.AgencyRecieve");
            i.putExtra("agencyname", agency);
            i.putExtra("phone", agencyphone);
            i.putExtra("email", agencyemail);
            i.putExtra("firstname", first);
            i.putExtra("lastname", last);
            startActivity(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(NewAgencyActivity.this, "Must Input All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                };


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call `agency.isEmpty()`, etc to check for empty strings (`""`).
2. If you want *all* the fields to be nonempty, use and (`&&`) instead of or (`||`).

Comment: when I try isEmpty() is says method is undefined. I tried agency.length() == 0 and it still let me submit empty fields.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29, although `agency.length() == 0` should work as well. Are you sure you are using `&&`?

Comment: Yeah, I changed to &&, I figured it out, I was using == instead of !=

Comment: Oh, you want `agency.length() != 0`.